# Python :: chaining generators for API call

Tags: python, generator

I am hitting an API whose responses consists of many pages, say, 100.

This takes too long, so I am trying to use `generators` so I can `yield` values for each page and process until some `condition` is met down the pipeline.

```
import requests
import json
import itertools as it
```

I am defining this `generator` to make requests:

```
def api_query(query):


    page=1
    while True:
         # do requests, then
         for result in body:    
            title = result["result"]["title"]           
            primaryartist_name = result["result"]["primary_artist"]["name"]

            yield title, primaryartist_name

        page+=1
```

then, I want to filter the first page response using this other `generator`:

```
def api_filter():

    api_response = api_query('query') 
    # 10 first results
    page1 = [api_response.next() for i in range(10)]
    # do some filtering with page1 results
    yield results
```

lastly, I test it for the `condition` and try to `return` my desired values:

```
def api_print():

    results = api_filter()

    page1 = list(it.islice(results, 5))
    # check if page1 results satisfy a given condition
    if condition:
        return page1
    # or try next page
    else:
        page2 = list(it.islice(results.next(), 5))
            return page2
```

however, at this last bit of code, I can only print page1; if the code moves to `else`, I get

`page2 = list(it.islice(results.next(), 5)) StopIteration`

what am I doing wrong?

ps: sorry if this is a non working example; full code is too long, so I am using a simplified question in order to test the concept of generators in this case...

Comment: Can you clarify why do you want to chain generators? why not do all of the requesting, filtering, condition-checking in just one generator? generators are supposed to be simple, sequence iterating objects. if you wish to filter or check a condition maybe you should consider using `map()` or some other ways... and as [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says "Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated."

Comment: to make code more readable, and also because I've seen some examples of generators working in chains, using consumers and producers, using the send method. but I don't understand the concept too well.

Comment: The expression `it.islice(results.next(), 5)` looks like it's probably a typo, since `results.next()` is a single value from the previous generator. I suspect you just want `results` in the `islice` call (like you do in the previous one for `page1`). I'd also note that your code is a bit hard to understand since you've clearly cut out a lot of stuff. Can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue? That is, code that can actually be run?